# PHP7's substr() behavior on null/empty strings

Tags: php, string, substr

I was reading the PHP manual for [substr()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), in which it states the following about the input string parameter:

> **string**
>
> The input string. **Must be one character or longer**.

But further down the page in the examples section, this was one of the examples:

```
// ...
echo "6) ".var_export(substr("", 0, 1), true).PHP_EOL;
// ...
```

This obviously contradicts the specification for the input string which was required to be **one character or longer**. The page stated the output of the above would be `6) ''`.

Coming from a C/C++ background I'm very careful of UB, so I would like to know if passing a `NULL` or `""` to `substr()` is legal?

Comment: Why not just try it instead of posting it as a question? https://3v4l.org/KsZCN

Comment: I've obviously tried it before asking, but the fact that it's returning something isn't a complete indication that it didn't do something funny (or that could just be because C/C++ made me paranoid about not following function specs).

Comment: It works, but it's not legal. That means that there's a good chance a future version of PHP will make it not work completely. There's also a good chance a future version of PHP will drop that note from the manual completely and make it officially legal. Right now it should be treated as unspecified behaviour.

Comment: There is a big difference in passing `NULL` and `""` to any function.  If something has returned null and I was intending to use this value, I would have thought there should be some logical point where you would branch out to some form of error handling anyway.

Comment: You may want to fill a bug report so they can correct documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you should take the PHP manual statements litterally, in particular for well-established core language functionalities. Here is a demo, for what it's worth.

https://3v4l.org/8RKbG .

IMO, you should be fine with an empty string (current implementations are protected against and I don't see that changing anytime soon). There is certainly no harm done in getting empty strings out of the way before calling `substr()` either.

A null value, however, seems to trigger a warning under HHVM (and only there), which is interesting. But the relevance of this fact is completely up to you.